# How can I display the completion state of an activity without refreshing the page?

Tags: moodle

Activities in a course have checkboxes on the right where they can tick them as they finish an activity or the platform does it automatically if certain conditions are met. When it's set to automatic, the webpage needs to refresh before displaying the checks on each completed activity. This presents a problem in that if an activity is a video set to play in a pop-up video, which is the case of my platform, the users won't know they have finished an activity until they reload said page.

All the documentation I've read suggests that there isn't a way of accomplishing this with Moodle's functionality, it's a limitation of the system. Still, I ask in case anyone here has an idea on how to solve this.

Some of the ideas I have are to simply set all videos to embed, meaning the user will have to navigate between pages circumventing the problem. Another is to set the platform to refresh every set amount of time but this is evidently not a great solution.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it fast and dirty, I would write some custom JS that, on opening the popup, requests via ajax an updated version of the current page (GET against the current URL) and replaces the specific check with the updated one via ajax content replacement and some jquery selectors magic, then I would get sure that the event handlers that hang on those replaced checks are still working, otherwise I would freshly re-set them.

An alternative more elegant way would be to write a web service (external function as it is called in Moodle) that checks for the completion of the activity after the popup has been opened (just once or periodically) and then replaces just the check with the one that represents the updated completion state (then, again, see if the check event handlers still work after the replacement).